# Checkout Page Stencil Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

We use Bigcommerce Stencil theme for our store, but we have some issue with a checkout page.  We don't need have Shipping Details before Shipping Method because we have only Click&Collect option, without shipping. How can we change an order of questions in a checkout page and put Shipping Method before Shipping Details or maybe just hide it, as you pick Click&Collect option? Is it possible to change checkout.php or maybe add some JavaScript code for this? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world that is the walled garden of Big Commerce "Do it my way or not at all". I suspect the answer is no, but this is a comment rather than an answer because I too am struggling with Big Commerce and it's surprising limitations.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to modify what is happening on the checkout page by making your changes to checkout_express.html.

In Stencil, I found that the checkout_express.html file may not be available in the Stencil Theme Editor (Storefront Design -> My Themes, click on the "Customize" button on your current theme).  If this is the case, you may need to go and change the setting for your checkout to allow for modification.  Go to Advanced Settings -> Checkout and select "Custom One Page Checkout (for developers)" and Save your changes.  This will set you up to be able to edit checkout_express.html.

Next, go to Storefront Design -> Design Options, and select the "More" navigation item.  You should now have the option "Template Files".  Selecting this option will give you a list of files for the current template; checkout_express.html should be among them.  Find the file, and click on the ellipsis (...) on the right side of the screen for the file and select "Edit".  That should open a new window with an in-browser editor that will allow you to make adjustments to the checkout page layout as you see fit.